​She doesn't have got an apple. She hasn’t got an apple. Which one is correct?
​She doesn't have got an apple.
She hasn’t got an apple.
Which one is correct?
Or both them are correct? Thanks!
And why.
I am a english learning beginner. Thank you for your answers.

How did you construct these sentences? What sources did you reference, and what are you still confused about? Questions on this site should show evidence of research.

It's hasn't got or doesn't have. You can't combine the two usages into doesn't have got or hasn't does got. Note that TO HAVE is the "main" verb in both cases, and that's all you need for the non-negated utterance She has an apple - which in principle can be negated by She has no apple, but we usually introduce TO DO or TO GET (not both) as a  "helper verb" when negating.

...in very casual speech, some people discard TO HAVE and use "I got an apple" instead of "I have an apple" or "I have got an apple". I do not recommend that style to learners.

there are differences in dialect.  See the duplicate question about "I don't have time" and "I haven't got time". The first is wrong. The second is right. The first could be "He doesn't have an apple" (no "got")

@JamesK Why is "I don't have time [to stop and chat]" Wrong? You could say the second (I haven't got time) is more common in BrEng but the don't construction is equally acceptable.

I don't say that.  I do say that "I don't have got time"  would be wrong @Mari   Ah.  I see, my comment was badly phrased.  I meant the first in the OP's examples above,
